# changing CF9 root directory wwwroot to Sites on mac

Tags: coldfusion, installation, root

I have installed CF9 development edition and would like to change the web folder to Sites on my mac rather than wwwroot in the coldfusion 9 folder.

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Thanks,

R.

Comment: yes, the web root folder

Answer (score 1):

You sure can.  Here are the instructions:
[link text](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Admin/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbf363a5d-7ffc.html)

Add any other questions you have.

Answer (score 1):

(On windows) I usually just modify the web root path in jrun-web.xml.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Admin/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbf364104-7fd8.html

ie

```
<virtual-mapping> 
    <resource-path>/*</resource-path> 
    <system-path>C:/ColdFusion9/wwwroot</system-path> 
</virtual-mapping>
```